# Repetições e combinações de valores

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

Tenho uma tabela (quina) com 5 campos, cada campo pode ter o valor de 1 a 80.

Gostaria de saber se é possível em SQL ou apenas no Delphi, pegar os duques (combinações de 2 números) entre 1 e 80 nos campos de c1 ate c5. não importando onde se encontram os valores na linha.

**Exemplo:** combinação de 01 e 02: *20 vezes*.

(Mas o 01 pode estar no c1, c2 ou c3, e o 02 pode estar no c4 ou c5. O mesmo número não pode se repetir na mesma linha).

Answer (score 2):

--alinhando

```
select c1 c from tabela
union all
select c2 c from tabela
union all
select c3 c from tabela
union all
select c4 c from tabela
union all
select c5 c from tabela
```

--lendo como uma tabela

```
select virtual1.*
from
(
select c1 c from tabela
union all
select c2 c from tabela
union all
select c3 c from tabela
union all
select c4 c from tabela
union all
select c5 c from tabela
) virtual1
```

--forcando um cartesiano

```
select virtual1.*,virtual2.*
from
(
select c1 c from tabela
union all
select c2 c from tabela
union all
select c3 c from tabela
union all
select c4 c from tabela
union all
select c5 c from tabela
) virtual1,
(
select c1 c from tabela
union all
select c2 c from tabela
union all
select c3 c from tabela
union all
select c4 c from tabela
union all
select c5 c from tabela
) virtual2
where virtual1.c <. virtual2.c
```

A ideia básica é fazer um "unpivot" da tabela e depois forçar um cartesiano.

Comment: nossa, eu vou tentar, e mando uma resposta

Comment: o v1 e v2 seriam os valores correto? entao eu colocaria 1.*, 2.*? porque ele está dando erro de sintax no from do primeiro select select v1.*, v2.*

Comment: É o "alias" da tabela virtual , montei com um nome e chamei por outro , corrigido ...

Comment: infelizmente nao deu certo. eu fiz em delphi, mas ele demora uns 30min para finalizar as leituras.. porque ele combina os valores X e Y em todos os campos e em toda as linhas e ainda faz a soma dos mesmo.

Comment: O que deu errado ?